# Radio button validation error in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have two radio button for selecting gender. and used below JS but if 'female' button is selected it takes it but if 'male' is selected it showing that none is selected.

```
var r = document.getElementsByName("sex")
var sex= -1;
for(var i=0; i <= r.length; i++)
    {
         if(r[i].checked)
            {
            sex = i; 
            }
    if (sex == -1)
    { 
        alert("please select gender");
        return false;
    }    
}
```

i have taken two div for two radio with same name for both radio.
so here is my html to check if problem is there,

```
<div style="margin-top:17px; width:92px;float:left;">
   <input id="female" class="radio" type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female</input>
</div>
<div style="margin-top:17px; width:92px;float:left; margin-bottom:17px;">
   <input class="radio" id="male" type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male</input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There where some issues.

- JavaScript is zero-index based. You ran a loop with `i <= r.length`, this means that your loop will go outside the node list's boundary. It iterates three times, where it should iterate only two times.
- The if statement is in the for loop, it should be outside, since it should only be executed once.

```js
function validate()
{

  var r = document.getElementsByName("sex")

  var sex= -1;
  for(var i=0; i < r.length; i++)
    {
         if(r[i].checked)
         {
            sex = i; 
            break;
         }
    }
    if (sex < 0)
    { 
        alert("please select gender");
        return false;
    }
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", validate, false);
```

```html
<div style="margin-top:17px; width:92px;float:left;">
   <input id="female" class="radio" type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female</input>
</div>
<div style="margin-top:17px; width:92px;float:left; margin-bottom:17px;">
   <input class="radio" id="male" type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male</input>
</div>

<button>Validate</button>
```

Comment: i dont know much about use of snippet but , this showing to select a gender when trying to validate after selecting male.

Comment: @sajansahoo found some issues I overlooked in your original code. Try it now.

Comment: 'need to be in the same container to work' why this? The selection of this example is given by name and without any child-selectors.

Comment: @dsuess, wow a long time ago (yet somehow into the future) radios needed to be in the same container. This is no longer so, correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can simplify the logic and replace for-loop by an more explicit 'selected'-check.
Furthermore, please note, to have clickable text labels for radio buttons, to use *text*, as it is non standard and would not work correctly with most browsers.

```js
function validateFn() {
  if (document.querySelectorAll('[name=sex]:checked').length == 0) {
    alert('please select a sex')
  }
}

document.querySelector('[type=button]').addEventListener('click',validateFn, false);
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input id="female" class="radio" type="radio" name="sex" value="female" />
    <label for="female">Female</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="radio" id="male" type="radio" name="sex" value="male" />
    <label for="male">Male</label>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="validate"/>
</form>
```

This code will select all elements with *name = sex*, which are selected. In case of radio buttons this only can be one or nothing.
For this selection query "document.querySelectorAll" is used, which is quit mor powerfull than getElementByName/Id/ClassName..., see http://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp.
Also, the selection uses "pseudo-states" or "pseudo-classes", see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp